# Building a print driver that does not render files- just copy-pastes them

Tags: printing, rendering, drivers, print-job-control

Does anyone know how to build a print driver where the print job processor does not do any rendering to the file, but just copy pastes the original job file to a destination?

All the virtual printer drivers I have seen at least convert the print order to another format (usually PDF) or they render it. I am looking to build a driver that simply copy-pastes the order to a certain path.

Would appreciate any guidelines on how to do this.

Thank you in advance.